# Hardware Emulated Performance on Arch Linux in Android Studio

Tags: android, linux

I've been using Linux rather then Windows as my primary operating system, mostly using Jetbrains IDEs and Android Studio. But, I have one question/issue which still cannot solve. **Why I can't have hardware rendering in Emulated Performance, upon creating Android Virtual Device?** Whenever I choose that, it's only saying: *waiting for device to come online...*, I've installed all libraries I've could possibly find on Google. Using Software Rendering is awfully slow, making my application testing almost impossible. Gradle build also takes very long time.

Do I really need to switch over to Windows? (It's working on Windows, so I'm assuming I'm missing something?)

VT-d is disabled in BIOS as I couldn't even make AVD with it being enabled.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#vm-linux ?

Comment: Yes, but cannot manage to install on Arch, as this is for Ubuntu. Precisely, I'm using Antergos who's based on Arch Linux.

Comment: what is your cpu brand/model?

Comment: CPU: Intel Core i5 4440 @ 3.3 GHz, GPU: AMD R9 380 2GB MSI Armor2x. I think this is pretty much capable of running without any bigger issues. It's paired along with 8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz CL10 G.Skill RipJaws memory.

Comment: did anybody solve this?